# CSS Guidance on Aligning Grid Items in Boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a grid of items and the pictures are all different heights and widths, and the details can be long or short causing differing numbers of line breaks across the page.

This is what I want it to look like:
[image]

And here is what it actually looks like:
[image]

Here is how I've structured the HTML for each item (Note, this whole thing is included in the loop as it marks up the grid):

```
<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-center item'>
    <div class='item-image'>
        <a href='#' >Delete Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' /></a>
        <img class='img-circle img-responsive img-center' src='#' />
    </div>

    <div class='item-details'>
        <h3>Product Name 
            <small>$$price</small>
        </h3>

        <p class='detail'>Date Added</p>
        <p class='detail'><a href='#' target='_blank'>View Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-new-window' /></a></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see, I'm not really using anything other than Bootstrap, the details class is just font sizes. Here are my issues:

1. If images are wider than others, it may make the image shorter (if the aspect ratios are different) and I know this is due to the img-responsive from Bootstrap, since the width is set by Bootstrap to auto.
2. The Text below the box doesn't have any impact on the overall row height, but I don't know why. I guess I assumed that the row would resize based on the largest divs within it? I could set the rows manually, but I'm trying to keep it responsive so once you go to the mobile breakpoint the grid is 2-wide instead of 4.

I'm not sure what to search for, I can't seem to find any guidance on this issue.

Comment: Also.. apologies ahead of time, if it's not 100% clear with this post, I'm not a front-end guy :)

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/ i think is solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to clear the float that's applied to the item at the right breakpoint since you have items of varying sizes at multiple breakpoints.

See [MDN Clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) and here are the built in [utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) for Bootstrap3 but probably don't make sense inside of your loop.

See example Snippet.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .item:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .item:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center item'>
      <div class='item-image'>
        <a href='#'>Delete Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' /></a>
        <img class='img-circle img-responsive img-center' src='http://placehold.it/350x150' />
      </div>

      <div class='item-details'>
        <h3>Product Name 
            <small>$$price 1</small>
        </h3>

        <p class='detail'>Date Added</p>
        <p class='detail'><a href='#' target='_blank'>View Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-new-window' /></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center item'>
      <div class='item-image'>
        <a href='#'>Delete Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' /></a>
        <img class='img-circle img-responsive img-center' src='http://placehold.it/350x250' />
      </div>

      <div class='item-details'>
        <h3>Product Name 
            <small>$$price 2</small>
        </h3>

        <p class='detail'>Date Added</p>
        <p class='detail'><a href='#' target='_blank'>View Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-new-window' /></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center item'>
      <div class='item-image'>
        <a href='#'>Delete Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' /></a>
        <img class='img-circle img-responsive img-center' src='http://placehold.it/350x350' />
      </div>

      <div class='item-details'>
        <h3>Product Name 
            <small>$$price 3</small>
        </h3>

        <p class='detail'>Date Added</p>
        <p class='detail'><a href='#' target='_blank'>View Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-new-window' /></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center item'>
      <div class='item-image'>
        <a href='#'>Delete Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' /></a>
        <img class='img-circle img-responsive img-center' src='http://placehold.it/350x250' />
      </div>

      <div class='item-details'>
        <h3>Product Name 
            <small>$$price 4</small>
        </h3>

        <p class='detail'>Date Added</p>
        <p class='detail'><a href='#' target='_blank'>View Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-new-window' /></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center item'>
      <div class='item-image'>
        <a href='#'>Delete Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' /></a>
        <img class='img-circle img-responsive img-center' src='http://placehold.it/350x350' />
      </div>

      <div class='item-details'>
        <h3>Product Name 
            <small>$$price 5</small>
        </h3>

        <p class='detail'>Date Added</p>
        <p class='detail'><a href='#' target='_blank'>View Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-new-window' /></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center item'>
      <div class='item-image'>
        <a href='#'>Delete Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' /></a>
        <img class='img-circle img-responsive img-center' src='http://placehold.it/350x250' />
      </div>

      <div class='item-details'>
        <h3>Product Name 
            <small>$$price 6</small>
        </h3>

        <p class='detail'>Date Added</p>
        <p class='detail'><a href='#' target='_blank'>View Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-new-window' /></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center item'>
      <div class='item-image'>
        <a href='#'>Delete Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' /></a>
        <img class='img-circle img-responsive img-center' src='http://placehold.it/350x450' />
      </div>

      <div class='item-details'>
        <h3>Product Name 
            <small>$$price 7</small>
        </h3>

        <p class='detail'>Date Added</p>
        <p class='detail'><a href='#' target='_blank'>View Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-new-window' /></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center item'>
      <div class='item-image'>
        <a href='#'>Delete Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' /></a>
        <img class='img-circle img-responsive img-center' src='http://placehold.it/450x250' />
      </div>

      <div class='item-details'>
        <h3>Product Name 
            <small>$$price 8</small>
        </h3>

        <p class='detail'>Date Added</p>
        <p class='detail'><a href='#' target='_blank'>View Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-new-window' /></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center item'>
      <div class='item-image'>
        <a href='#'>Delete Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' /></a>
        <img class='img-circle img-responsive img-center' src='http://placehold.it/250x450' />
      </div>

      <div class='item-details'>
        <h3>Product Name 
            <small>$$price 9</small>
        </h3>

        <p class='detail'>Date Added</p>
        <p class='detail'><a href='#' target='_blank'>View Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-new-window' /></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This in conjunction with the min-height feedback is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Add a div wrapping four element with class="row"

```
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-center item'>
        <div class='item-image'>
            <a href='#' >Delete Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' /></a>
            <img class='img-circle img-responsive img-center' src='#' />
        </div>

        <div class='item-details'>
            <h3>Product Name 
                <small>$$price</small>
            </h3>

            <p class='detail'>Date Added</p>
            <p class='detail'><a href='#' target='_blank'>View Item <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-new-window' /></a></p>
        </div>

    </div
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-center item'>
          .... second

    </div
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-center item'>
          .... third

    </div>
      <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-center item'>
          .... fourth

    </div>
</div>
```

in case

try adding a proper min height (the max img height)  to your `itemn-details` class..

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. I actually forgot to mention that there is already a <div class="row"> that is wrapping this loop.

Comment: well then the problem is only related to teh fact you have img with different size.. you should use a fixed size for this div/element or adding a min height I have update the asnwer..

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge, this is helpful.