# Bootstrap - 4 column grid breaks after certain point

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im having a problem figuring out why the bootstrap grid seems to be breaking after a certain point in my demo, it appears like this, ***don't mind the top part(col-sm-9 and col-sm-3), it's in it's own row.*** so far at 13 items it appeats like this:

[image]

14 items like this, as you can see image didnt start from the left as it should:

[image]

At 23 items it appears like this:[image]

This is an abnormality because I think it appears differently based on which images I add, but all images are classed with "img-responsive".

HTML: http://pastebin.com/f4wqhuL8
CSS: http://pastebin.com/8sCvUzbL

Comment: Could you possibly post HTML here or on JSFiddle?

Comment: I added the paste bins with both HTML and CSS

Comment: I'm thinking there is some whitespace behind every image making the parent wider than it should. Please put everything together in a JSFiddle so we can view it more easyly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Guidance on Aligning Grid Items in Boostrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840873/css-guidance-on-aligning-grid-items-in-boostrap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused by the inner elements of the columns having different sizes, probably due to the images been different sizes. To fix this, either change the images all to the right sizes where they are all relevant to the column and row they are in or use CSS to force the size of the inner elements.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. The image height has nothing to do with it

Comment: This will be happening in a php while loop so i'll have no say on what size image the user uploads. I was just testing it out static to see how it would appear after a number of images and saw that. They all have the class "img-responsive" which as I understand sets them to the right sizes.

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you use just one image repeated x times instead of all different images?

Comment: Thanks Luke, I was about to mark your reply as answer because I set all images with width "263px" then saw grid fixed itself.

Then I tried downloading a larger image (1920x1352) and adding it to the mix and it broke the grid again :/ this is going to be dynamic so I need user to be able to upload any dimension they want but grid should make it responsive.

Comment: As long as the ratio of the images are kept the same this shouldn't be an issue, you'll be able to keep it responsive and display it inside a simple loop.

Comment: Thanks Luke, I set a static width and height and that seem to have fixed the issue. I thought class "img-responsive" would automatically set the correct height and width for the images but it didnt..It seem to only make them "scale" properly without loosing their quality.

Answer (score 3):

Looking only on your image previews: it is probably due to that image with man on the rock has wider ratio than other images.

---

**Quick check:** divide height/width of your images, and if your image with man on the rock has smaller ratio it's proof for my assumptions.

---

**Change from image to background-image**

**html**

from

```
<div class="article-tile">
    <img src="img/fig.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
    <span class="text-overlay-articles">Hello World</span>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="article-tile" style="background-image: url(img/fig.jpg);">
    <span class="text-overlay-articles">Hello World</span>
</div>
```

**css**

from

```
.article-tile{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /*width: 107%;*/
  position: relative;
}
```

to

```
.article-tile{
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   position: relative;
   height: 300px; //or what you prefer, you should change this value on other resolution with @media query
   width: 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

or `background-size: contain;` if you prefer always display whole image and don't bother not equal spaces between images.

Comment: when I use "measure dimensions" chrome extension Some images are different by 1 px, that breaks the grid, when I set a static width and send another bigger image into the mix, whole grid breaks again

Comment: So this 1px make a difference, since bootstrap columns are based on floating left

Comment: Thanks Everettss your method would work also I'm sure but Luke made me understand that I had to set a width and a height.

I thought "img-responsive" would have taken care of the sizes but I after I set a static width and height it worked.

I upped your answer so you can get some rep, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your columns with a `row` if you want 4 columns per row then wrap these four columns in their own row

**DO**

```
<section class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</section>

<section class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</section>
```

**Instead of**

```
<section class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  .....
</section>
```

Comment: You could do it like that, but it would break the fluid approach he is trying to achieve. Also it won't allow for different ratios of images.

Comment: thats just another way of doing it but not ideal since this is going to be in a while loop.

Comment: @RajaKhoury is right. This is proper approach since Uriahs Victor only show 4 images in row above xs resolution.
This approach will be more problematic if he would like to use for example <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div>

Comment: @UriahsVictor You can do it in a loop. Count the numbers of columns / records and add a row ...