# How to avoid gaps when a responsive grid shrinks?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I have a page laid out as a grid using Bootstrap:

**HTML**

```
<div class="postrow row">
   <article class='post-listview col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'>
      <div class='articleinner'>
         <div class='thumbandtitle'>
            <img src="x" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
            <div class="post-overlay">
               <div class="post-overlay-text">
                  <h2><a href="x">abc</a></h2>
                  <p>xyz</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <p class='post-info'>
            <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
            <span class='separator'></span>
            <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
            <span class='separator'></span> 
            <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
         </p>
      </div>
   </article>
</div>
```

The grid is responsive as intended, thanks to the `col` classes. However, when shrunk, any individual box (`<article>`) may become taller or shorter than the rest due to wrapping of its contents. And when that happens, it results in huge gaps between rows as shown below:

[image]

How can I eliminate those gaps? I tried using a `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after the `row` div but it didn't help because these gaps are appearing when the row itself wraps on smaller screens. On larger screens, the grid looks perfect:

[image]

**UPDATE**: This is not a duplicate of the question indicated by vanburen because the answers suggested in that question recommend using min-height which is not something I want. I need my grid items to be interlocked whereas using min-height on the elements (`article` tags) will still cause gaps WITHIN those elements if their content is less than what would fill in the min-height.

**UPDATE TO VANBUREN'S ANSWER**: Here's why your solution doesn't work for me...the gaps are still there, except that they are now less conspicuous:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Guidance on Aligning Grid Items in Boostrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840873/css-guidance-on-aligning-grid-items-in-boostrap)

Comment: If you take the time to read the accepted answer to the question in the duplicate you'll see it has nothing to do with setting a minimum height in any way. There are countless answers on SO that directly relate to your question (that clear the float of columns) so you should take the time to search and read them.

Comment: The accepted answer suggests using `clear:float` based on specific screen widths which isn't a viable option for me because a) it's manual and screen sizes can vary wildly, and b) adding `clear:float` on my `<article>` tag still didn't remove the gap, just moved it from left to right. Anyway, thanks for being immensely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the Documentation although this is not ideal in many cases so you'll need to handle this yourself.

> With the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues
>   where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as
>   one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a
>   `.clearfix` and our [responsive utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

Your setup is only utilzing 2 Breakpoints: (LG and XS since your MD and SM are the same size as XS See [Media Queries](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries))

*"it's manual and screen sizes can vary wildly"* I'm at a loss for how this actually relates since your specific grid is designed to hold 4 columns above 1200px and 2 columns below (`col-lg-3 col-xs-6`). You simple need to clear those columns at their respective breakpoints just as it shows in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840873/css-guidance-on-aligning-grid-items-in-boostrap) I linked to.

See working example Snippet.

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .post-listview:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .post-listview:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="postrow row">

    <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="articleinner">
        <div class="thumbandtitle">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
          <div class="post-overlay">
            <div class="post-overlay-text">
              <h2><a href="#">ONE</a></h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchangeLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="post-info">
          <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="articleinner">
        <div class="thumbandtitle">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
          <div class="post-overlay">
            <div class="post-overlay-text">
              <h2><a href="#">TWO</a></h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchange Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchange
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="post-info">
          <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="articleinner">
        <div class="thumbandtitle">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
          <div class="post-overlay">
            <div class="post-overlay-text">
              <h2><a href="#">THREE</a></h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchange.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="post-info">
          <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="articleinner">
        <div class="thumbandtitle">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
          <div class="post-overlay">
            <div class="post-overlay-text">
              <h2><a href="#">FOUR</a></h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchange setting industry. Lorem Ipsum has be</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="post-info">
          <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="articleinner">
        <div class="thumbandtitle">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
          <div class="post-overlay">
            <div class="post-overlay-text">
              <h2><a href="#">FIVE</a></h2>
              <p>xyz</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="post-info">
          <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="articleinner">
        <div class="thumbandtitle">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
          <div class="post-overlay">
            <div class="post-overlay-text">
              <h2><a href="#">SIX</a></h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchange Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="post-info">
          <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="articleinner">
        <div class="thumbandtitle">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
          <div class="post-overlay">
            <div class="post-overlay-text">
              <h2><a href="#">SEVEN</a></h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="post-info">
          <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="articleinner">
        <div class="thumbandtitle">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
          <div class="post-overlay">
            <div class="post-overlay-text">
              <h2><a href="#">EIGHT</a></h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchange Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="post-info">
          <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
      <div class="articleinner">
        <div class="thumbandtitle">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
          <div class="post-overlay">
            <div class="post-overlay-text">
              <h2><a href="#">NINE</a></h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="post-info">
          <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
          <span class="separator"></span>
          <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED for Masonry Layouts**

You're tying to build a Masonry layout which isn't native to Bootstrap. You can apply this [jQuery Plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to your grid to acheive this though. (also see [imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/))

```js
$('#masonry-container').imagesLoaded(function() {
  $('#masonry-container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.post-listview'
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.post-listview {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/4.1.0/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.0.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="postrow row">
    <div id="masonry-container">

      <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="articleinner">
          <div class="thumbandtitle">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
            <div class="post-overlay">
              <div class="post-overlay-text">
                <h2><a href="#">ONE</a></h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                  book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchangeLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                  standard</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="post-info">
            <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>

      <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="articleinner">
          <div class="thumbandtitle">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
            <div class="post-overlay">
              <div class="post-overlay-text">
                <h2><a href="#">TWO</a></h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                  book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, rema
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="post-info">
            <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>

      <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="articleinner">
          <div class="thumbandtitle">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
            <div class="post-overlay">
              <div class="post-overlay-text">
                <h2><a href="#">THREE</a></h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="post-info">
            <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>

      <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="articleinner">
          <div class="thumbandtitle">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
            <div class="post-overlay">
              <div class="post-overlay-text">
                <h2><a href="#">FOUR</a></h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                  book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchange setting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dum</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="post-info">
            <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>

      <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="articleinner">
          <div class="thumbandtitle">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
            <div class="post-overlay">
              <div class="post-overlay-text">
                <h2><a href="#">FIVE</a></h2>
                <p>xyz</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="post-info">
            <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>

      <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="articleinner">
          <div class="thumbandtitle">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
            <div class="post-overlay">
              <div class="post-overlay-text">
                <h2><a href="#">SIX</a></h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                  book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchange Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="post-info">
            <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>

      <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="articleinner">
          <div class="thumbandtitle">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
            <div class="post-overlay">
              <div class="post-overlay-text">
                <h2><a href="#">SEVEN</a></h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                  book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remain
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="post-info">
            <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>

      <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="articleinner">
          <div class="thumbandtitle">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
            <div class="post-overlay">
              <div class="post-overlay-text">
                <h2><a href="#">EIGHT</a></h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                  book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchange Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="post-info">
            <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>

      <article class="post-listview col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="articleinner">
          <div class="thumbandtitle">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive post-thumbnail">
            <div class="post-overlay">
              <div class="post-overlay-text">
                <h2><a href="#">NINE</a></h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                  book.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="post-info">
            <i class="post-icon post-date-icon fa fa-calendar"></i>time
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class="tagspan"><i class="post-icon post-author-icon fa fa-user"></i><a href="x">authorname</a></span>
            <span class="separator"></span>
            <span class='tagspan'><i class="post-icon post-tags-icon fa fa-tags"></i>tag1, tag2, tag3...</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See my update to the question. Like I said, this manual process doesn't completely eliminate the gaps...just moves them from one side to another.

Comment: Was not clear at all that you're trying to build a Masonry Layout. See updated answer.

Comment: Still think my question is a duplicate?

Comment: As I said, your question was not clearly stated at all with regard to using a masonry layout and this isn't an issue with Bootstrap in the first place. Also as stated in your question, **"On larger screens, the grid looks perfect:"** which there are clearly still gaps there so you can see how ambiguous the information is.